# Updating web content locally?

Tags: html, ide, local, web-hosting

I'm really new to owning a website, I just bought mine today!
But, I've found found pretty fast that updating files can be a nuance.
Make a change locally, save, re-upload.

I really prefer to code locally, as the IDE is much better. Else I'd have no problem coding with the hosts "notepad".

So, my question is, is there software of any kind that will sync your local files, to those that are hosted on the web host? Or is this dependent on the web host?

Comment: 1) Yes, you should always develop locally and upload the latest stable version when ready. 2) Entire books have been written about how to do that efficiently, and there are many questions about the topic for many different levels of experience. Maybe you want to look through those first. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=website+deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), i tell it to upload changed files, so once logged in, any changes i make locally are automatically updated. there are other ftp clients that do this also.

Comment: FileZilla worked better for me, I had connection issues with WinSCP.But, thanks for setting me on the right track!

Comment: just make suer you use SFTP, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a file versioning system like svn to download and update files, push new versions.  But that isn't really any different than what you are doing now, except that svn offers ability to keep track of previous versions and keep people from overwriting each other's work.  I think maybe you might mean more like "when I open and edit file.txt in my editor and save, it is automatically updated on the server" ?  If that is the case, there are a lot of editors that will let you open a file remotely and when you save it, it saves it remotely.  The one I personally use is html-kit

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant that, whenever I save, it updates to the server.

Comment: okay then yes.  It's pretty much same principle regardless of editor/ide but for instance with html-kit, you would go to workspace > add folder / ftp server > add ftp server and then enter in ftp info for your site and then it will appear in your files tab.  When you open it, it will ftp to your server and list the dirs and files and when you open a file, edit and save, it will save it remotely to your server.  But again, html-kit is just my personal favorite. There are a lot of editor/ftp or ide's out there that do the same thing

Comment: svn is a bit extreme for a personal web site worked on by one person, IMHO

Comment: maybe...then again, a lot of people make edits and save and somehow mess something up or otherwise want to revert back to some earlier version and unless you are diligent about manually saving previous versions (which most people aren't) you'd be kind of SoL on easily reverting.  svn will help keep track of that.  But if your editor of choice can be setup to automatically do the same thing, then sure, definitely do that instead.